# NServiceBus.Host.exe is crashing due to unhandled exception

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

We have seen this a few times. I'm sure there is some sort of NHibernate issue with MSDTC however why doesn't NserviceBus send the exception to the error queue instead of crashing the Host process? We have seen the exception in both 3.2.6 and 3.3.3

This also happened on the 17th before we did the endpoint upgrade at 7:34AM

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          12/17/2012 7:34:20 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      411357-SVCS01.daxko.local
Description:
Faulting application name: NServiceBus.Host.exe, version: 3.2.6.0, time stamp: 0x4ffd66f8
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e21213c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000cacd
Faulting process id: 0x2200
Faulting application start time: 0x01cddc556e2ef369
Faulting application path: D:\store\endpoints\Production\OnlineRegistrationEndpoint\NServiceBus.Host.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 75b6c18c-484e-11e2-b05c-0050568e4fb1
Event Xml:

  
    
    1000
    2
    100
    0x80000000000000
    
    40360
    Application
    411357-SVCS01.daxko.local
    
  
  
    NServiceBus.Host.exe
    3.2.6.0
    4ffd66f8
    KERNELBASE.dll
    6.1.7601.17651
    4e21213c
    e0434352
    000000000000cacd
    2200
    01cddc556e2ef369
    D:\store\endpoints\Production\OnlineRegistrationEndpoint\NServiceBus.Host.exe
    C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    75b6c18c-484e-11e2-b05c-0050568e4fb1

Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          12/17/2012 7:34:18 AM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      411357-SVCS01.daxko.local
Description:
Application: NServiceBus.Host.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.Disconnect()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Close()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Dispose(Boolean)
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistrubtedTransactionFactory+<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(System.Object, System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionCompletedEventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.DistributedTransactionOutcome(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction, System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.RealOletxTransaction.FireOutcome(System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OutcomeEnlistment.InvokeOutcomeFunction(System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ShimNotificationCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)

Event Xml:

  
    
    1026
    2
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    40359
    Application
    411357-SVCS01.daxko.local
    
  
  
    Application: NServiceBus.Host.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.Disconnect()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Close()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Dispose(Boolean)
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistrubtedTransactionFactory+<>c_*DisplayClass1.<EnlistInDistributedTransactionIfNeeded>b*_0(System.Object, System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionCompletedEventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.EnterState(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.DistributedTransactionOutcome(System.Transactions.InternalTransaction, System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.RealOletxTransaction.FireOutcome(System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OutcomeEnlistment.InvokeOutcomeFunction(System.Transactions.TransactionStatus)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ShimNotificationCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)

Comment: What kind of DB are you connecting to?  Does the MSDTC trace log say anything?  You can also turn on tracing from app.config.

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2. Not sure about the trace logs, I'll look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from the NServicebus forums that explains a fix and reason for NServiceBus not being able to handle the exception. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/17328

After googling this, it looks like it is a bug in NHibernate ( https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2420 ) that should have been fixed in > 3 versions!

The reason your endpoint crashed and nothing is sent to the error queue is because this is an unhandled exception in a background thread.

I'm not sure if there is anything we can do to prevent this from happening!

On 19 December 2012 04:20, porsche4me1999  wrote:
at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.Disconnect()

-- 
Regards
John Simons
NServiceBus

Comment: 2 day after the NHibernate upgrade we have not seen the issue occur again.